# Reading config file in DSL build on agent host

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I try to configure Jenkins' seed job, where whole business is in provided DSL script. I want to seperate that script from its configuration, which I want to locate in additional yml file. When I try to read that file:

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
def workDir = SEED_JOB.getWorkspace()
def config = new Yaml().load(("${workDir}/config.yml" as File).text)
```

I receive error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test.dsl/config.yml (No such file or directory)
```

I suppose that Jenkins is looking for the file on a master host, not an agent node where workspace is located. 
Is it possible to read yml file in DSL build step on the agent node? Or maybe I have to execute that seed job always on my master host?

Comment: There is some information missing, is there any checkout step done? Where is the config.yml file coming from?

Comment: File is from git repo which is cloned to workspace before DSL build step. But it doesn't matter if it's from repo or it was created manually. The file `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test.dsl/config.yml` exists, and user `jenkins` can read it.

Comment: Is your `jobDsl` call inside a `node` block? It would be helpful to see the whole pipelline script. Edit: nevermind, see the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950586/747579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems not possible as the jobDsl script is executed on master. You can try force to run the job on master with label `master`.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#seed-job) in section Script location:

> Job DSL scripts are executed on the Jenkins master node, but the seed job's workspace which contains the script files may reside on a build node. This mean that direct access to the file specified by **FILE** may not be possible from a DSL script. See Distributed builds for details.